# Add user32.lib to QtWidget project in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, linker-errors

I am a complete beginner to Qt. In a test scenario I need to call a user32 function for some reasons. My small application compiles, but does not link due to the missing user32.lib

Fixing this seemed to be straight forward, add library as shown below. But I cannot proceed to the next step as shown in the screenshot. I have tried almost every **library type / setting combination**, but the library path always appears in red and I cannot continue. I have even copied the lib on a drive root level in order to avoid any spaces in the path. Any hints?

Remarks:

1. This question ( [Linking to user32.lib in QTCreator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900275/linking-to-user32-lib-in-qtcreator) ) is a follow up situation after the library had been added this way. This is no duplicate.
2. Environment QtCreator 2.4.1 Win7
3. Workaround via `LIBS +=` found [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11023079/356726), but why is the dialog permitting me to continue?

[image: Add library in QtCreator]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of question [How to add an external .a library in Qt Creator project via GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727340/how-to-add-an-external-a-library-in-qt-creator-project-via-gui) I have found a working solution (added in .pro file):

```
win32 {
  LIBS += "P:\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\User32.Lib"
}
```

However, I am still interested **what I am doing wrong with the above dialog**?

**Remark**: Seems to be fixed, see mlvljr's comment below

Comment: plain 'LIBS += -luser32' working fine now, as of Qt 4.8.5 and MSVC 2010 SP1